# How to make this Route work in my ASP.NET MVC Application?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I want a route something like this:

> `MyController/Action/categoryid/productid`

So I made the following in my Global.asax file:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute(
      "Default", // Route name
      "{controller}/{action}/{categoryid}/{productid}",
      new { controller = "MyController", 
            action = "Action", 
            categoryid = UrlParameter.Optional, 
            productid = UrlParameter.Optional 
      } 
    );

    routes.MapRoute(
        "Default", // Route name
        "{controller}/{action}/{id}", 
        new { controller = "Home", 
              action = "Index", 
              id = UrlParameter.Optional 
        } // Parameter defaults
    );
}
```

But when I browse to `Mycontroller/action/2/3` the resource is not found.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**How does this code even build?** Defining `"Default"` as the route name **twice** must stop it being compiled.

Rename one of them to something else and it must work.

It is likely that your `action` has other parameters or you have defined `[HttpPost]` as attribute and you are using GET.

Comment: Yup! You got the right answer! I was using Duplicate names for the Routes!

Answer (score 1):

There is a great tool from Phil Haack called [ASP.NET Routing Debugger](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/03/13/url-routing-debugger.aspx) where you can type in various URLs in the address bar to see which route matches.

Answer (score 0):

This is want you want:

> {MyController}/{action}/{categoryid}/{productid},

But should give an more meaningfyll name to your MyController/Action part of the Url like Users/Edit/2/3

Comment: Yes! I do have meaningful names! This is just for posting here. This is what I want but what is yr solution!

Comment: Ok, then take a look at the Route debugger mentioned in other answers. It is a great tool.